# proget add package from nuget.org

Tags: nuget

I would like to add a few packages to proget from nuget.org.
For example I am trying to add NLog but get an error:

The package could not be installed.

The package was not found in the remote repository.

[image]

It seems to work if I download the packages to disk first and then upload them.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. This seems specific to NLog though, as I can install other packages just fine (e.g. log4net, nlog.config). I used `https://www.nuget.org/api/v2` as the feed though (slightly different from yours @Damian). I've reported it to the ProGet support team, let's see.

Comment: Did proget support ever get back to you?
It might just be a firewall issue at my end.
As a workaround I found out I can manually upload them.

Comment: @Damian Yes, they did. They couldn't reproduce the issue in the latest version (4.7.12) and suggested this might have been fixed as part of another nuget-related bug fix. We haven't upgraded our version here yet so I can't say whether this has / hasn't solved the issue. Like you, I ended up uploading the package manually.